# Does "бросаться на кого-н" mean laying into someone verbally or physically?

Tags: значения

> Тише, тише, не надо **на меня** так **бросаться**.

I mean, depending on context, can it be "verbally laying into someone" or "physically laying into someone"?

When you hear this sentence, for instance, do you imagine someone hurling abuse at someone else? Or is it more like picking a fight?

Comment: in a physical sense a colloquial synonym is ***кидАться***, it also denotes an act done out of passion, impatience (*бросился целовать*) or hastily (*бросаться спасать*, *бросаться на помощь* - to rush to help, *бросаться наутёк* - to take flight)

Answer (score 2):

It can be either. In the given context, judging by the tone, the assault was probably mostly verbal. But the original meaning of **(на)броситься на** (to throw oneself at someone) implies physical interaction:

- Яков бросился на него с кулаками.
- Пьяный Чуйков бросился на Родимцева и хотел задушить его.

Not to be confused with:

- Броситься на помощь/выручку кому-л. = Dash to help someone.
- Броситься на шею (к) кому-л. = Throw oneself at someone and hug them around the neck: Узнала меня и в слезах бросилась на шею.

People can throw themselves at arbitrary objects, not just other people:

- Кондуктор бросился на площадку.
- Он ушёл, а я бросился на диван и закрыл глаза. [И. С. Тургенев. Ася (1858)]

Bonus question. Do you think this implies physical contact?

- Первым долгом я, конечно, бросился на Измаила Александровича. (М. А. Булгаков. Записки покойника)

Comment: Verbal, I take it? :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be translated *literally*, with the meaning (verbal of physical) depending on the context:

> Hey, slow down, don't **come at me** like that.